# Matango: Attack of the Mushroom People: Nature of aggression?

Tags: matango

This is a movie that I saw as a little kid, probably not long after its production and it is an exceptionally effective horror movie. The idea that people eat the mushrooms even knowing that they will be transformed and the very last scene is really something. My question is, when the mushroom people "attack" just what are they doing? Trying irrationally to injure normal people or trying to spread the disease?

As I recall, the mushroom people did not seem very dangerous and it appeared as if they were just trying to make contact with the skin of humans.

It just occurs to me that while I am Legend and Night of the Living Dead are pointed to as seminal zombie movies, is not Matango another example of a very early "zombie" movie, even if the affected are not exactly zombies (but really pretty much are)? This is also the great-grandfather of *The Girl with all the Gifts* and *The Last of Us* as a writer suggests here at [Buzz Feed](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/josephbernstein/the-obscure-1960s-horror-movie-that-may-have-inspired-the-la).

I would then also mention that the original work from 1907 The Voice in the Night is perhaps the first story about zombies as we understand the term today, not the book I am Legend (which is of course still a very good story, influential and very different from The Voice in the Night).

Comment: In _The Last of Us_ the infected attack so they can spread the spores, given the nature of the infection and that it is very similar to Matango, and possibly is inspired by it, I’d imagine that is the case here too.

Comment: In the last of us, seems like the infected try to injure/kill humans with the side effect being that the humans also become infected.

Comment: I believe they attack to spread the spores with the side effect being injury and maybe death. The wiki for it agrees with that interpretation too. I’m not 100% sure though. It does make sense for that to be the case with this sort of “zombie” though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I think we can agree that zombies ain't too smart and no amount of instruction would result in them not occasionally killing instead of simply spreading the contagion. Can't be helped; we all do the best we can.